# Is it possible to get mods to run on the GOG Mac version of Fallout?

Tags: mods, macos, fallout

I want to install Fixt on Fallout 1 for mac, but I cant seem to find anything that allows me to do that. Is it possibe?

Comment: You're asking two different things here; are you LOOKING for a mod, or are you trying to INSTALL a mod?

Comment: @Frank I don't see two questions. He wants to install the Fixt mod. He can't find anything about how to do so.

Comment: @Frank I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Hebon Do you already have the mod and just need instructions?

Comment: @Frank Yes. Well, what I mean to say is that I can download it, but since it's only for windows at the moment, I haven't. I own the GOG version of Fallout 1 and 2 also.

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  You want to know if the Fixt mod is available for Mac, and if so, how to install it. Correct?

Comment: @Frank Yes, but I would love to install any mod if possible. I am mainly focused on Fixt though.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far. If anyone could give me a reasonable answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sbuibek has been working on an OSX version of the "fixes only" installer, which you can find [here](http://www.nma-fallout.com/showthread.php?50313-Fallout-1-FIXT-megamod-for-Mac-OSX/page2). It is currently in alpha state.